# IE 7 bug on dropdown select

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

When i click to dropdown, the options appear, but right before i get a chance to select, it disappears. It work just fin on other browsers but not in IE 7 - .
You can see the problem here: http://www.lovgreens.com/shop/cleanses/6-juice-per-day-cleanse/

I trided the fixes from this post but nothing worked so far http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: IE7 is 8 years old, who really cares about supporting it?

Comment: Anyone with IE7 out there to test that ?

Comment: @PeteR unfortunately some people do care..

Comment: I wasn't having a go at you, but if you keep frigging valid code to run on buggy and obsolete browsers, then people will never upgrade. As a web developer you should be forcing people to upgrade by refusing to support these defunct pieces of crap. Harsh, I know, but you have to draw the line somewhere and 8 years is as good a time to start as any.